# compiling curl with HipHop for PHP Patch

Tags: ubuntu, curl, patch

I'm following this guide: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Building-and-installing-on-ubuntu-10.10

It want's me to download curl source, doing the patch and compile this. well, but i get those silly error saying:

```
libtool: link: gcc -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -o .libs/curl main.o
hugehelp.o urlglob.o writeout.o writeenv.o getpass.o homedir.o
curlutil.o os-specific.o strtoofft.o strdup.o rawstr.o nonblock.o 
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so -lrt -lz -Wl,-rpath
-Wl,/var/hphp/dev/hiphop-php/../lib ../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined
reference to `SSLv2_client_method' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [curl] Fehler 1 make[2]: Verlasse Verzeichnis
'/var/hphp/dev/curl-7.21.2/src' make[1]: *** [all] Fehler 2 make[1]:
Verlasse Verzeichnis '/var/hphp/dev/curl-7.21.2/src' make: ***
[all-recursive] Fehler 1
```

I tried to find things on Google, but those patches didn't work.

Edit 1: I'm using Ubuntu 11.10

Edit 2: I found this: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/pull/322 but well. it didn't fix my curl compiling problem.

Comment: I suggest you take your 3:d edit and put it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted the following lines of code: [github.com/bagder/curl/commit/26b487a5d6ed9da5bc8e4a134a88d3125884b852](http://github.com/bagder/curl/commit/26b487a5d6ed9da5bc8e4a134a88d3125884b852) Seems to work now!